# trouble with update_option() in WordPress import settings function

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am having a bit of trouble with an import/export option I'm building into my theme. Hopefully I explain this well, let me start with the function.

```
function ifeature_import_options() {
$options = get_option('ifeature');
$import = $options['if_import_code'];

if ($import != '');
    $options_array = (unserialize($import));
        foreach( $options_array as $option_name => $option_value ) {
        update_option( $option_name, $option_value );
        }
}
```

`if_import_code` returns the serialized output of `$options` (which the user enters into a textarea in my options panel), and I've tested that `$options_array` is properly unserializing the import code as it prints the following:

> Array ( [if_menu_color] => Pink [if_font] => Arial [if_css_options] =>
>   [if_favicon] => [if_ga_code] => [if_import_code] => [if_export_code]
>   => b:0; [if_logo] => [if_menuicon] => [if_header_contact] =>
>   [if_facebook] => [if_twitter] => [if_linkedin] => [if_youtube] =>
>   [if_googlemaps] => [if_email] => [if_rsslink] => [if_home_description]
>   => [if_home_keywords] => [if_home_title] => [if_callout_title] =>
>   [if_callout_text] => [if_callout_img] => [if_callout_image_link] =>
>   [if_slider_type] => posts [if_slider_placement] => feature
>   [if_slider_category] => [if_slider_posts_number] => [if_slider_height]
>   => [if_slider_delay] => [if_slider_animation] => random
>   [if_footer_text] => [if_hide_callout] => 0 [if_show_fb_like] => 0
>   [if_hide_slider] => 0 [if_hide_boxes] => 0 [if_hide_link] => 0
>   [if_slider_navigation] => 0 )

So I have the new array that needs to be written to my options, but the update_options code I've used isn't working. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

$options_array = unserialize($importOptions);

```
foreach ($options_array as $option_name=>$value) {
    if ($value != '') update_option( $key, $value );
}
```